# Set jest node_module folder path in CRA project

Tags: reactjs, configuration, jestjs, node-modules

I have a CRA project, the whole app and its package.json file are located inside the `/app` folder, so does the node_module folder.

I use vs code and I installed the jest extension, when I try to run a single test by click right button and then `run test`, I get the following jest error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/my_user_name/myApp/node_modules/.bin/jest'
```

As you can see it looks for jest in the wrong folder, it should be instead:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/my_user_name/myApp/app/node_modules/.bin/jest'
```

Any suggestion where I can change this setting?

I know there's a VS Code setting called `jest.pathToJest` but it doesn't work for my case.